# If $p$ is a prime, then prove that $(p−1)!+1$ is a power of $p$ if and only if $p = 2$, $3$, or $5$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is $(p - 1)! + 1$ a power of $p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287957/when-is-p-1-1-a-power-of-p)

> If $p$ is a prime, then prove that $(p−1)!+1$ is a power of $p$ if and only if $p = 2$, $3$, or $5$.

I could not find an initial step with which I could prove the above stated statement.

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I think this question has been asked before but am unable to find the duplicate question.

Comment: @Marvis Yes I saw it before