# What steps have been taken so far to solve Brocard's Problem?

Tags: factorial, square-numbers, conjectures, open-problem

The equation is $$n!+1=m^2$$ where $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers. [Brocard's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem) asks whether there are solutions for n other than $4, 5, 7$. The only improvement I have found that people have done toward solving the problem is that if the [ABC conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) is true, then there are finite solutions for $n$. However, this is all I have found, [despite having at least one reward for it.](http://unsolvedproblems.org/index_files/Prizes.htm) **What other things do we know about Brocard's Problem?**

Comment: I don't think the money is a great stimulant, the fact that you've solved a famous open problem is already so great. Besides you will be offered high-paid jobs everywhere.

Comment: @wythagoras True, so I wonder why it's been overshadowed by more prominent conjectures like ABC's or Beal's or Goldbach's?

Comment: From the link to the prize: "the solution must be published on the Unsolved Problems web site prior to any acceptance by a peer-reviewed journal or conference" That's more than a little shady (and arrogant to boot! The person at that web page thinks they can determine correctness better than wide exposure to experts in the respective fields of the problems?)

Comment: @Meelo Hmm, that's true. I'll take that off.

Comment: Dis UnsolvedProblems really offer \$1000 for Beal's conjecture and the RH? That is quite stupid (\$1M has been offered for both)

Comment: @HyperLuminal ABC has far more consequences for other problems in number theory (e.g. for Brocard's problem as you mentioned). Goldbach is one of the longest open problems. Beal's conjecture gained much attention through Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: @wythagoras I see. What impact would this problem have on mathematics in general if it were proven or disproved?

Comment: @HyperLuminal Not much. The fact that we know the solutions to some equation, doesn't tell us anything about other equations or problems.

Comment: On the other hand, the methods used to prove it may well have much wider application.

Comment: A simple observation:  if Brocard's problem is true for some $n$, and $n+1 = p$ is prime, then $p$ must be a Wilson prime.  There are only three Wilson primes less than $2 \times 10^13$ -- 5, 13, and 563.  Only $p=5$ (so $n=4$) gives rise to a solution to Brocard's problem.  This rather reminds me of the classic problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287957/when-is-p-1-1-a-power-of-p.  Unfortunately, that clever solution doesn't transfer well to Brocard's problem.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I see a "proof" of it on ResearchGate [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316110458_SOLVING_THE_BROCARD_PROBLEM) by a high school student, but its presence is relatively unknown. Is it incorrect?

Comment: We can start be using difference of squares:
$$n! = m^2 - 1$$
$$n! = (m-1)(m+1)$$